# config.xml not loading properly

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I have created a custom module probably 20 times and it is showing the same 404 error.

I have searched for an issue and eventually found nothing.
isn't it because I am using ubuntu.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

This is my `app/etc/Kuldeep_HelloWorld.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kuldeep_HelloWorld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Kuldeep_HelloWorld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This is `app/code/local/Kuldeep/HelloWorld/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Kuldeep_HelloWorld>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Kuldeep_HelloWorld>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <helloworld>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module/>Kuldeep_HelloWorld</module>
          <frontName>hey</frontName>
        </args>
      </helloworld>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
<admin>
  <routers>
    <helloworld>
     <use>admin</use>
     <args>
      <module>Kuldeep_HelloWorld</module>
      <frontName>admin_helloworld</frontName>
     </args>
    </helloworld>
  </routers>
</admin>
<global>
  <helpers>
    <helloworld>
      <class>Kuldeep_HelloWorld_Helper</class>
    </helloworld>
  </helpers>
</global>
<adminhtml>
 <menu>
   <helloworld module="helloworld">
     <title>HelloWorld</title>
     <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    <children>
      <helloworld module="helloworld">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        <action>admin_helloworld/adminhtml_index</action>
      </helloworld>
    </children>
   </helloworld>
 </menu>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

This is controller file:
`app/code/local/Kuldeep/HelloWorld/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class Kuldeep_HelloWorld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

   /**
   * Index action
   *
   * @access public

   * @return void
   */
   public function indexAction() {

      echo "it works!";

   }

   public function doneintagainAction() {

      echo "done it again....!!!!";
      }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you give full permission to `app/etc` folder?

Comment: What URL are you using to try and view the module? Your `frontname` is set to `'hey'`, so your url would be like `your-magento.com/hey/index/`

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your etc/config.xml:

```
<module/>Kuldeep_HelloWorld</module>
```

If you notice in the first module tag, you have a slash. Change it to this:

```
<module>Kuldeep_HelloWorld</module>
```

Also, you never noted which URLs you are trying. Could you post those?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/hey

Comment: <module>Kuldeep_HelloWorld</module>
correted the syntax error but still showing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

`app/etc/Kuldeep_Helloworld.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kuldeep_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Kuldeep_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Kuldeep/Helloworld/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kuldeep_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Kuldeep_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <helloworld>
                <class>Kuldeep_Helloworld_Helper</class>
            </helloworld>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Kuldeep_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>hey</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Kuldeep_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>admin_helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <helloworld module="helloworld" translate="title">
            <title>HelloWorld</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <helloworld module="helloworld" translate="title">
                    <title>Hello World</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/menu/index</action> //adminhtml controller
                </helloworld>
            </children>
        </helloworld>
    </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Kuldeep/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class Kuldeep_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

   public function indexAction()
   {
       echo "it works!";
   }

   public function doneintagainAction()
   {
       echo "done it again....!!!!";
   }
}

/*you dont need to close a php tag-> "?>" */
```

**NB:** you need an adminhtml controller for your menu, the first one that you created was for frontend.

`app/code/local/Kuldeep/Helloworld/controllers/Adminhtml/MenuController.php`

```
<?php

class Kuldeep_Helloworld_Adminhtml_MenuController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('menu/menu')
            ->_title($this->__('Submenu1'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```